# Does any shell dynamically append history?

Tags: shell, command-history

Does any shell dynamically append history, such that the history survives a crash?

Comment: AFAIK Bash does it only after exiting.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of relevant options in zsh:

Quoting the manual (see [`info zsh appendhistory`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#History)):

> ```
> APPEND_HISTORY <D>
>      If this is set, zsh sessions will append their history list to the
>      history file, rather than replace it.  Thus, multiple parallel zsh
>      sessions will all have the new entries from their history lists
>      added to the history file, in the order that they exit.  The file
>      will still be periodically re-written to trim it when the number of
>      lines grows 20% beyond the value specified by $SAVEHIST (see also
>      the HIST_SAVE_BY_COPY option).
>
> INC_APPEND_HISTORY
>      This option works like APPEND_HISTORY except that new history lines
>      are added to the $HISTFILE incrementally (as soon as they are
>      entered), rather than waiting until the shell exits.  The file will
>      still be periodically re-written to trim it when the number of
>      lines grows 20% beyond the value specified by $SAVEHIST (see also
>      the HIST_SAVE_BY_COPY option).
>
> INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME
>      This option is a variant of INC_APPEND_HISTORY in which, where
>      possible, the history entry is written out to the file after the
>      command is finished, so that the time taken by the command is
>      recorded correctly in the history file in EXTENDED_HISTORY format.
>      This means that the history entry will not be available immediately
>      from other instances of the shell that are using the same history
>      file.
>
>      This option is only useful if INC_APPEND_HISTORY and SHARE_HISTORY
>      are turned off.  The three options should be considered mutually
>      exclusive.
>
> SHARE_HISTORY <K>
>
>      This option both imports new commands from the history file, and
>      also causes your typed commands to be appended to the history file
>      (the latter is like specifying INC_APPEND_HISTORY, which should be
>      turned off if this option is in effect).  The history lines are
>      also output with timestamps ala EXTENDED_HISTORY (which makes it
>      easier to find the spot where we left off reading the file after it
>      gets re-written).
>
>      By default, history movement commands visit the imported lines as
>      well as the local lines, but you can toggle this on and off with
>      the set-local-history zle binding.  It is also possible to create a
>      zle widget that will make some commands ignore imported commands,
>      and some include them.
>
>      If you find that you want more control over when commands get
>      imported, you may wish to turn SHARE_HISTORY off,
>      INC_APPEND_HISTORY or INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME (see above) on, and
>      then manually import commands whenever you need them using 'fc
>      -RI'.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

bash can, just set PROMPT_COMMAND to (or to include) 'history -a'.
See the 'history' built-in command and the PROMPT_COMMAND variable in 'man bash' for full details.